# Maven: Set Manifest Class-path with different prefix according to each dependency

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I have a Pom.xml which contain 3 dependencies

1. Selenium - contains jar (a)Selenium-java.jar (b)Selenium-api.jar
2. Jsoup - contains jar (a)jsoup1.7.jar
3. POI - contains jar (a) poi.1.7.jar (b) poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar

I want to create a manifest with classpath where I can control the classpath prefix of every dependency.

I have tried

```
<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>                         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```

but it does not solve the problem as it adds the same prefix in the classpath for all dependency.

src

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Expected : 'Selenium/Selenium-java.jar Selenium/Selenium-api.jar Jsoup/jsoup1.7.jar POI/poi.1.7.jar POI/poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar'

Actual   : 'lib/Selenium-java.jar lib/Selenium-api.jar lib/jsoup1.7.jar lib/poi.1.7.jar lib/poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar'

Comment: I am very sure you do not really need that. What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: I want to make a runnable jar of my project and these dependencies are kept in their respective folder.
 I want that this runnable jar should use these dependencies using classpath. I cannot make a runnable jar (with dependencies) as I have multiple projects that use the same dependencies.
 In short, I have all dependencies kept in their respective folder and I want that each of my project runnable jar can use this dependency using classpath.

Comment: I do not understand why you cannot just bundle the dependencies into your jar? It is no problem to bundle the same dependency into multiple jars.

Comment: Suppose the Dependencies size is 20 mb. I have 5 projects jar. If I bundle the dependencies in each jar then overall size increase is 100mb. Instead of this if I kept the dependencies in some location and every jar refer to these dependencies then it can save me 80mb memory. I just want to make the overall jar size as less as possible.

Comment: Ok. But still you need to explain why you cannot just put all the jars in the same `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, I know, you can try following: https://maven.apache.org/shared-archives/maven-archiver-2.5/examples/classpath.html#Custom